# Get real user windows login name if connection authorized by SQL auth and impersonated

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to get windows login name of connection to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 if connection is made with SQL auth? In addition - impersonation is used. I can only get real host name.

I guess it's not possible because it's against impersonation idea. But could you make me sure?

Answer (score 3):

If connection is made using SQL auth then there is absolutely no way of retrieving the 'windows login name', irrelevant of whether the connection was made under an impersonated context or not. An alternative could be to use an out-of-band process like [session context information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but the applicaiton has to cooperate and appropriately set the context info on each connection Open. If you have a requirement like audit the original Window Login that executed an action then SQL auth must be replaced with Windows auth.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. Application (by another vendor) should put operator ID into Program_Name() but id does not. Thanks for a tip with CONTEXT_INFO() - new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once the connection is establish using Windows Integrated Authentication then it is simple:

```
declare @userid varchar(15)

SELECT @userid = nt_username 
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE spid = @@SPID

select @userid
```